# How to set image from image id in layout from layout id

Tags: android

Here i got id of both layout and image, now i want to show image in layout
image id is viewPlayer and Layout id is viewLayout

```
public class ResponseHandler extends AsyncResponseHandler {


        public ResponseHandler(Activity context) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.e("ResponseHandler onFinish Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {


            try {

                Debug.e("ResponseHandler", "onSuccess" + response);

                if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {

                    Log.e("cur_player", Constants.PLAYER);
                    MovePiece styleListRider = new Gson().fromJson(
                            response, new TypeToken<MovePiece>() {
                            }.getType());


                    Log.e("value_updated", "" + styleListRider.position);

//                    getResId(styleListRider.position, ImageView.class);

                    int idLayout = getResources().getIdentifier(styleListRider.position, "id",
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    View viewLayout = findViewById(idLayout);
                    int idPlayer = getResources().getIdentifier(Constants.PLAYER, "id",
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    View viewPlayer = findViewById(idPlayer);


                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.e("ResponseHandler onSuccess Exception", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String content) {

            Debug.e("Response ", "onFailure" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its a unclear what you are saying.

Comment: i got ids of view from server side now i want to add view on that id

Comment: Pan kya set karva che ? Screenshot share kar

Comment: viewLayout.setBackgroundResource(viewPlayer); like this

Comment: got solution .thanks

Comment: Drawable d = ((ImageView)viewPlayer).getDrawable();

 viewLayout.setBackground(d);

Comment: Saru kevay... Ketlo time bagdyo ema ?